# 404 on create_intent via solidus_stripe gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, solidus

Trying to integrate v3 intents , followed the readme but i keep getting thoses errors on js side :

```
Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “payment”. v3:1:78187
Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “payment”. v3:1:78325
Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “payment”. v3:1:178554
```

and when i submit the test card informations :

```
POSThttps://_my_web_site_url.com/stripe/create_intent [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 897ms]
```

I keep searching for what kind of integration error i could've done but nothing , i have the feeling it lack a memeber of the posting url
all mentions in stripe's doc are specifying a version in them .

i'am running

```
rails 5.2.6 on ruby 2.7 with:
solidus (2.10.5)
solidus_api (= 2.10.5)
solidus_backend (= 2.10.5)
solidus_core (= 2.10.5)
solidus_frontend (= 2.10.5)
solidus_sample (= 2.10.5)
solidus_api (2.10.5)
solidus_stripe (4.2.0)


config.static_model_preferences.add(
Spree::PaymentMethod::StripeCreditCard,
'stripe_env_credentials',
secret_key:'sk_test_aksdhflkajsgdflkuasgdf',
publishable_key: 'pk_test_kjhga;lihglkashglasd',
stripe_country: 'FR',
v3_elements: false,
v3_intents: true,
)
```

And the stripe static conf has been selected in the backend's payment page .

A rails route show the  available urls , but not available to js nor by direct typing in url bar .

THanks in advance for reading / helping .

Answer (score 1):

i've posted an issue to the gem's repo.

To make it works i had to add routes in my main app's route.rb :

`post '/stripe/confirm_payment', to: 'stripe#confirm_payment'`

`# payment intents routes:`
`post '/stripe/create_intent', to: 'solidus_stripe/intents#create_intent'`
`post '/stripe/create_payment', to: 'solidus_stripe/intents#create_payment'`

`# payment request routes:`
 `post '/stripe/shipping_rates', to: 'solidus_stripe/payment_request#shipping_rates'`
`post '/stripe/update_order', to: 'solidus_stripe/payment_request#update_order'`

would not recommend this gem .